# VSCode autocomplete and IntelliSense are not working within backticks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with Gatsby project. When I type code inside backticks(`), template literals, VSCode doesn't show IntelliSense or autocomplete. I installed a bunch of snippet extensions. But that didn't seem to solve the problem. I'm using Prettier extension, can that cause this?

```js
import React from "react"
import MainMenu from "./MainMenu"

import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');

// Autocomplete and IntelliSense are not working in this part and it's pretty slow to type styles without those.
//
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
`;
const LayoutWrapper = styled.div`

//Here same thing
//
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <MainMenu />
    <LayoutWrapper>{children}</LayoutWrapper>
  </div>
)

export default Layout
```

[image]

Comment: What language is this? This looks like JS/TS, in which case backticks are basically strings, IntelliSense does not execute inside strings afaik.

Comment: Yes it's JavaScript.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

VS Code does not ship with built-in support for [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com) style inline css. Try installing this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

It adds syntax highlighting and IntelliSense for styled-components in js and ts:

[image: Intellisense for inline css]

Comment: It seems like it is deleted from the marketplace.

Comment: And the alternatives don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

Matt Bierner is correct, VSCode seems to not support it.

Try:

1. `Cntrl+P`
2. Paste this: `ext install vscode-styled-components`
3. Choose **vscode-styled-components** to install (See below):

[image: Correct Plug-in]

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
 "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
  },
```

You want the `"strings": true` (default is `false` I believe) for intellisense within backticks, i.e., template literals.

Comment: That worked and now IntelliSense shows up. But IntelliSense doesn't show CSS related suggestios in JS file. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: I see this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paulmolluzzo.convert-css-in-js

Comment: This extension is a life saver!

Comment: This is the right answer and should be accepted, it answers the question about back-ticks and uses VSCode directly

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `import styledcomponents from 'styled-components'`
I did `import styled from 'styled-components'`

It's silly, but it worked for me.

```
const wrapper = styled.div
```

Not

```
const wrapper = styledcomponents.div
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add :
In package.json

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  }
}
```

Then:
include in your tsconfig.json:

```
"plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-styled-plugin",
        "tags": [
          "styled",
          "css", /*and others that you like it!*/
        ]
      }
    ],
```

And the magic comes !

Answer (score 1):

You can get the auto-complete feature in styled-components using  this extension of VS-Code:
NAME: vscode-styled-components
LINK:   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

This helped me in the same scenario otherwise earlier everthing insde the  backtick(`) was red coloured.